# get all variation images (additional variation images woocommerce plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I need to retrieve all the images of a variation, I can get the first image with 
      `$variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
      $updated_image_id = $variation->get_image_id('edit');`

but how can I get all the additional variation images if I know the variation id?

Comment: the variations have several images? or do you want to loop through the variations?

Comment: The variations have several images. I want to loop through the images of a single variation.

Comment: try switching `$variation->get_image_id('edit')` with `$variation->get_gallery_image_ids();` should give you a array of the image ids in the gallery.

Comment: depending on your woocommerce version - If it is an old one, use `$variation->get_gallery_attachment_ids();`

Comment: The gallery is empty, the images are in the variation. They are stored in the database table wp_postmeta with key '_wp_attached_file' but with their own post id, I cannot join with a variation id.

Comment: I am also getting the same problem. $variation->get_gallery_attachment_ids(); returns me an empty array however there are images present against the variation in the admin panel. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this - Not tested though.

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $variation_id,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image' 
);
$images = get_children( $args );

if ( empty($images) ) {
    // no attachments here
} else {
    foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
        //Do whatever here
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'full' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass `$variable_id`:

```
//displays thumbnail picture
echo "<img src=" . wp_get_attachment_url($product->get_image_id()) . " />"; 

//displays other pictures from WooCommerce Additional Variation Images
$imagesIDS = get_post_meta($variable_id, '_wc_additional_variation_images', true ); 
$imagesArray = explode(",", $imagesIDS);
foreach ($imagesArray as $imageID) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $imageID, 'full' );
}
```